# vb.net get full path and filename of active excel workbook

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel

I had this code working a few days ago, but forgot to save the working copy. It took me 4 weeks just to find this answer and would not like to take that much time again, so...

Everything here works, except the **objWorkBook** lines, which return the error:
"Variable 'objWorkBook' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime."

Any suggestions?

```
Dim objExcel As Excel.Application = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
Dim objWorkBook As Excel.Workbook

Dim totalWorkBooks As Integer = objExcel.Workbooks.Count
MsgBox(totalWorkBooks & " is Number of Open Workbooks")

Dim ActiveBookIndex As Integer = objExcel.ActiveWindow.Index
MsgBox(ActiveBookIndex & " is Active Window Index")

Dim FullName As String = objWorkBook.FullName
MsgBox(FullName & " is FullName")

Dim OnlyName As String = objWorkBook.Name
MsgBox(OnlyName & " is Name without the Path")
```

I forgot what Value I had assigned.

My objective is to compare an open Excel Workbook name with one in a known location so that if they match, my program can proceed. I need the code above so I can compare it to the following code in an If-Then so that my program can proceed.

```
Dim dir As String = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
Dim FullFileName As String = dir & "\My_File_Name.xlsx"
```

On a positive note, I pieced together A solution, even though it's not the answer I was looking for....

```
Dim p() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Excel")
Dim Title As String = p(0).MainWindowTitle
Dim dir As String = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
        Dim FullFileName As String = dir & "\" & Replace(Title, "Microsoft Excel - ", "") & ".xlsx"

MsgBox(dir)
MsgBox(Title)
MsgBox(FullFileName)
```

This will work for now, but I would like to solve it the other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line

`Dim objWorkBook As Excel.Workbook`

to

`Dim objWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing`

Also your `objWorkBook` object is not assigned to anything before you are trying to use it in the line `Dim FullName As String = objWorkBook.FullName`

Is this what you are trying?

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim objExcel As Excel.Application = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
        Dim objWorkBook As Excel.Workbook

        Dim totalWorkBooks As Integer = objExcel.Workbooks.Count
        MsgBox (totalWorkBooks & " is Number of Open Workbooks")

        Dim ActiveBookIndex As Integer = objExcel.ActiveWindow.Index
        MsgBox (ActiveBookIndex & " is Active Window Index")

        '~~> Set the workbook to say first workbook.
        '~~> You can use a loop here as well to loop through 
        '~~> the workbooks count
        objWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks(1)

        Dim FullName As String = objWorkBook.FullName
        MsgBox (FullName & " is FullName")

        Dim OnlyName As String = objWorkBook.Name
        MsgBox (OnlyName & " is Name without the Path")

        '
        '~~> Rest of the code
        '
    End Sub
End Class
```

**EDIT**: Followup from comments

> But let's say I have 9 Workbooks already open, how do I get me app to index, manipulate, switch between them... without knowing the Full Path and File Names ahead of time?

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim objExcel As Excel.Application = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
        Dim objWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
        Dim FullName As String = ""
        Dim OnlyName As String = ""

        Dim totalWorkBooks As Integer = objExcel.Workbooks.Count
        MsgBox (totalWorkBooks & " is Number of Open Workbooks")

        For i As Integer = 1 To totalWorkBooks
            objWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks(i)

            With objWorkBook
                FullName = .FullName
                OnlyName = .Name

                MessageBox.Show (FullName & " is FullName and " & OnlyName & " is Name without the Path")

                '
                '~~> Rest of the code here to manipulate the workbook. For example
                ' objWorkBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "Blah Blah"
                '

            End With
        Next i

        releaseObject (objExcel)
        releaseObject (objWorkBook)
    End Sub

    '~~> Release the objects
    Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
        Try
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject (obj)
            obj = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            obj = Nothing
        Finally
            GC.Collect()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: if you don't then how will you set your `objWorkBook` object :)

Comment: My previous solution didn't use the Index of the ActiveWindow.

Comment: Then how can use the `objWorkBook` object if you do not assign anything to it? How is the code supposed to understand which workbook are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry removing my reply to your post, still new to this comment section...

Your reply in in answer to my (accidently removed) statement "My previous solution didn't use the Index of the ActiveWindow."

I'm building an app that does API calls and prints the Resp to Excel. Knowing that the user may open and close Excel while my app is still running, (as a first time programmer) I've just been renaming them: objExcelA, objExcelB, objExcelC.... if there are any seeming conflicts. Still need to learn how to Release them, maybe?

Comment: See [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/vb-dot-net-and-excel/) on how to release Excel Objects

Comment: Thanks for the useful link. I noticed that there are no instructions on how to interact with Excel **without creating it yourself.** Our apps can manipulate Excel if our apps created them, OR do the same for the Active Workbook. But let's say I have 9 Workbooks already open, how do I get me app to index, manipulate, switch between them... without knowing the Full Path and File Names _ahead of time_?

Comment: `how do I get me app to index, manipulate, switch between them... without knowing the Full Path and File Names ahead of time?` That is what the code that I gave does. If all the workbooks are opened in the same instance of Excel then you can use a for loop to loop through all the open workbooks. For example `For i = 1 to totalWorkBooks` and then using `objWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks(i)`

Comment: I tried your example. I get: "A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in CodeTesting.exe" in reference to "Dim ActiveBookIndex As Integer = objExcel.ActiveWindow.Index". I Tried both of these: "Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" and "Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"... same results.

Comment: Ok... THANK YOU... especially for your patience. I, um, apparently had an additional Instance of Excel running that hadn't closed. Might have been messing with things. But it's working very well, now.. again... THANK YOU